# Pandas: compare list objects in Series

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataframe a column is made up of lists, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[1,2],[2,4],[3,1]]})
```

I need to find out the location of list [1,2] in this dataframe. I tried:

```
df.loc[df['A'] == [1,2]]
```

and

```
df.loc[df['A'] == [[1,2]]]
```

but failed totally. The comparison seems very simple but that just doesn't work. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The only thing you're "missing" is that data frames aren't really great for storing lists. Any reason you don't want two separate columns?

Comment: @BallpointBen Thanks for your attention, I've posted a new question to explain the whole question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115592/pandas-how-to-compare-several-cells-with-a-list-tuple

Comment: @Luuklag This may be a duplicate, but I don't believe it's a duplicate of the target you suggest. That one seems to be trying to filter based on whether multiple columns are equal to particular values. This one is trying to check if the list *is equal to* a single column's value, which has a very different answer.

Comment: Feel free to suggest a more appropriate target.

Comment: @Luuklag, I posted the two questions because I don't think they are the same. As jpmc described, they are connected but also very different. This post is actually the varietas of that one: I tried stupid things to solve that one and based on the stupid thing I posted this one. But this one still has its distinct value. Can you please remove the duplicate target?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do not use `list` in cell, it creates a lot of problem for `pandas`. If you do need an `object` column, using `tuple`:

```
df.A.map(tuple).isin([(1,2)])
Out[293]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
#df[df.A.map(tuple).isin([(1,2)])]
```

Comment: Could you explain why a tuple is better? I've noticed that Pandas struggles when lists are in a cell, but does it handle tuples better because they are immutable? Would you expect a numpy array to work better than a list?

Answer (score 15):

You can use `apply` and compare as:

```
df['A'].apply(lambda x: x==[1,2])

0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

---

```
print(df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: x==[1,2])])

        A
0  [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 9):

#### With Numpy arrays

```
df.assign(B=(np.array(df.A.tolist()) == [1, 2]).all(1))

        A      B
0  [1, 2]   True
1  [2, 4]  False
2  [3, 1]  False
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution! [Or, if possible, just expanding the series of lists to 2 series.]

Comment: Won't this run into issues if the lists are differently sized, though perhaps that's outside of the scope of this example.

Comment: @ALollz yes and yes

Comment: Nice! My only concern is, this solution converts datatype twice, what if my dataframe is very big, will this conversion cost more time?

Answer (score 6):

Using numpy

```
df.A.apply(lambda x: (np.array(x) == np.array([1,2])).all())

0     True
1    False
2    False
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
df['A'].apply(([1,2]).__eq__)
```

Then:

```
df[df['A'].apply(([1,2]).__eq__)]
```