# Pandas: how to compare several cells with a list/tuple

Tags: python, pandas

I need to compare some columns in a dataframe as a whole, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3],'B':[4,5,6]})

#Select condition: If df['A'] == 1 and df['B'] == 4, then pick up this row.
```

For this simple example, I can use below method:

```
df.loc[(df['A']==1)&(df['B']==4),'A':'B']
```

However, in reality my dataframe has tens of columns which should be compared as whole. Above solution will be very very messy if I choose to list all of them. So I think if regard them as a whole to compare with a list may solve the problem:

```
#something just like this:
df.loc[df.loc[:,'A':'B']==[1,4],'A':'B')]
```

Not worked. So I came up with the idea that first combine all desired columns into a new column as a list value, then compare this new column with the list. The latter has been solved in [Pandas: compare list objects in Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53102731/pandas-compare-list-objects-in-series)

Although generally I've solved my case, I still want to know if there is an easier way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Boolean mask via a NumPy array representation of your data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3],'B':[4,5,6]})

res = df[(df.loc[:, 'A':'B'].values == [1, 4]).all(1)]

print(res)

   A  B
0  1  4
```

In this situation, **never combine your columns** into a single series of lists. This is inefficient as you will lose all vectorisation benefits, and any processing thereafter will involve Python-level loops.

Comment: Could you please be more specific on the 'Numpy array representation'? Do you refer to the equation df.loc[:, 'A':'B'].values == [1, 4] ?

Comment: Sure, so [`pd.DataFrame.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) returns a NumPy array from a dataframe.

Comment: I see, does this mean Pandas stores numerical data in the form of Numpy array? That's interesting, I haven't realized that there is such a relation between Pandas and Numpy

Comment: @ShiangHoo, Yes, the entire Pandas framework is built on top of NumPy.

Answer (score 3):

Or use `[[]]` for getting multiple columns:

```
df[(df[['A','B']].values==[1,4]).all(1)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3],'B':[4,5,6]})
>>> df[(df[['A','B']].values==[1,4]).all(1)]
   A  B
0  1  4
>>>
```