# extract duplicated row based on anaother column condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given one dataframe

```
df1

#  CustomerId  Product      csp
#      adp141    Toaster     1
#      adp141    Toaster     4
#      65782     Toaster     1
#      65782     Radio       2
#      74285     Radio       1
#      45984     Radio       1
#      55868     Toaster     1
#      55868     Radio       4
#      adp485    Radio       1
#      adp485    Radio       1
```

I try to have the data duplicated on the id where I only have 1 and 4  in COLUMN (csp) with the same Id numbers in COLUMN (CustomerId   ):

How can I do to have this final dataframe

final result :

`#  CustomerId    Product       csp
    #      adp141    Toaster     1
    #      adp141    Toaster     4
    #      55868     Toaster     1
    #      55868     Radio       4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `filter`

```
df=df.groupby('CustomerId').filter(lambda x : pd.Series([1,4]).isin(x['csp']).all())
Out[72]: 
  CustomerId  Product  csp
0     adp141  Toaster    1
1     adp141  Toaster    4
6      55868  Toaster    1
7      55868    Radio    4
```

Answer (score 0):

This idea from @YOBEN_S was very helpful, and reminded me of the advantages of a tuple's immutability: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53102773/7175713)

Get the groupings of the `csp` column by `CustomerId` :

```
outcome = (df
           .groupby(["CustomerId"])
           .csp
           .agg(tuple)
           .isin([(1,4)])
          )

outcome

CustomerId
45984     False
55868      True
65782     False
74285     False
adp141     True
adp485    False
Name: csp, dtype: bool
```

Set `CustomerId` as the index and filter using the boolean expression from the `outcome` variable :

```
#you can add reset_index to match your expected output
df.set_index("CustomerId").loc[outcome]

             Product    csp
CustomerId      
  adp141    Toaster     1
  adp141    Toaster     4
  55868     Toaster     1
  55868     Radio       4
```