# Iterate through multiple Pandas list-type series and find matches

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DF containing three list-like series that I need to iterate through and compare against external lists to then create a True/NaN series for rows where exact matches of these external lists are found

Recreation code:

```
data = {
    "num_elements": [1,3,3,4], 
    "elements_bool_identifiers": [["Y"],["N", "Y"],["N"],["N"]], 
    "elements_identifiers": [["FOO"],["FOO", "BAR"],["FOOBAR"],["FOO", "BAZ"]], 
    "identifiers_selections": [["A"],["A", "B", "B"],["A", "B", "B"],["A", "B", "A"]], 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

valid_elements_bool_identifiers = "N"

valid_elements_identifiers = ["FOOBAR"] # (might be expanded in the future)

valid_identifiers_selections = ["A", "B", "B"]
```

The list series are at the same time a transformed set (.apply(set).apply(list))

Comment: potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53102731/pandas-compare-list-objects-in-series/53102773

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use tuples instead of lists :](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53102773/3965888)

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {
    "num_elements": [1,3,3,4], 
    "elements_bool_identifiers": [["Y"],["N", "Y"],["N"],["N"]], 
    "elements_identifiers": [["FOO"],["FOO", "BAR"],["FOOBAR"],["FOO", "BAZ"]], 
    "identifiers_selections": [["A"],["A", "B", "B"],["A", "B", "B"],["A", "B", "A"]], 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

valid_elements_bool_identifiers = ("N",)  # use tuple

valid_elements_identifiers = ("FOOBAR",)  # use tuple

valid_identifiers_selections = ("A", "B", "B")  # use tuple


df["match"] = ((df["elements_bool_identifiers"].map(tuple) == valid_elements_bool_identifiers) &
               (df["elements_identifiers"].map(tuple) == valid_elements_identifiers) &
               (df["identifiers_selections"].map(tuple) == valid_identifiers_selections))
df
```

[image]

Otherwise using lists you get error :

> ('Lengths must match to compare', (4,), (3,))

Comment: Hey @ismael-el-atifi - Thanks very much for your answer! It works perfectly on this sample code. However, strangely enough, on my live data it works right up until the last of the conditions (valid_identifiers_selections); when I pass all but that one it works fine, but when I include that I get NaN (also tried using .loc but I get the same result). I checked the type() of all sample and real data columns and they're all matching, but still it breaks. I will try and find what the problem is and if it all pans out, I'll accept your answer, but might come back to you otherwise.

Comment: Hey @ismael-el-atifi - Finally got this to work... The issue I was having with the identifiers_selections was with a previous bit on my code. That series was actually the result of a groupby object which I was applying a list to; that meant that the actual series was "[A , B , C ]" (note the spaces), I had to apply(str).str.replace(r"(?s)((?![AB]).)*", "", regex = True).apply(list) for this to work (I'm only interested in A/B results from this groupby).