# Fast way to filter for a value in a numpy array and get the DataFrame row

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have this DataFrame:

```py
pd.DataFrame({
    'as_of': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-05', freq='D'),
    'x': [np.array([str(np.random.random()) for _ in range(2)]) for _ in range(5)]
})
```

Imagine that this DataFrame with 50k rows and the numpy array size is variable, no more than 5 values though.

How can I filter the DataFrame to give me just the row that matches the value that is inside of the numpy array, in the most efficient manner?

Also, instead of a single value, how can I filter for the entire numpy array?

Comment: Don't use strings for one thing

Comment: Completely agree. It's out of my control.

Answer (score 1):

If you are guaranteed that there will only be one array in `x` with the value you want, you can use the following:

```py
search_val = 0.3

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'as_of': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-05', freq='D'),
    'x': [np.array([str(np.random.random()) for _ in range(2)]) for _ in range(5)]
})

# Add example row with array of different size and the value we are searching for
df.loc[5] = [pd.to_datetime('2020-10-06'), np.array([.1, .2, .3])]

# Gets the index of the array with the search value
df.loc[[(df["x"].explode() == search_val).idxmax()]]  # gives row 5
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to pass in search_val = np.array([.1, .2, .3]), how can I find its row?

Comment: Oh, if you're looking to compare against the whole array value, I'd suggest doing the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53102731/pandas-compare-list-objects-in-series).

`search_arr = (.1, .2, .3)` then `df[df["x"].map(tuple).isin([search_arr])]`

Comment: I can do `df['x'].isin([search_arr])` but I'm getting this warning: `FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison`